# SWF decompiler that does not break code

Tags: flash, actionscript, decompiler

So I need a bit of help here. I am looking for an SWF decompiler that does not break the code. I have tried jpex and trillix but they mess it up.
Does anyone know one that does not?

Comment: I don't think you're going to get anything better. Decompilation is hard, and "messing" things up is inevitable whenever only a binary is available.

Comment: This question is off-topic. Only coding related questions are acceptable. If you are attempting to crack someone's code then, you should be aware, its a crime. You could simply ask for source code. If the SWF belongs to you, you should have source code.